# Replacing character(0) with NA

Tags: r, web-scraping

I a retrieving html_nodes from multiple sides. Now, when a value is not available for a specific info R returns character(0). I want to replace replace this outcome with NA when it happens.

I have tried the following, which does convert character(0) to "NA", but unfortunately also all valid outcomes. What am I doing wrong?

```
Meta_Pre_MinContri <- html_text(html_nodes(data1, '.contribution-size 
.value'))
        Meta_Pre_MinContri <- 
Meta_Pre_MinContri[Meta_Pre_MinContri=="character(0)"] <- "NA" #NA if 
char(0)
```

Comment: are you missing a comma? Is that a data frame?, Maybe this `Meta_Pre_MinContri[Meta_Pre_MinContri=="character(0)",] <- NA`

Comment: I can see two assignment operator in one line, this might be the reason your code not working.

Comment: I also don't know if `Meta_Pre_MinContri=="character(0)"` is the right syntax as it would look for a character string "character(0)". This should work though: `Meta_Pre_MinContri[!length(Meta_Pre_MinContri) > 0] <- NA`

Comment: @JonGrub: works perfectly! Thank you! It was not a dataframe, just a single variable for now

Comment: If it works, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two issues in your code. One is that you have two assignment operators in one line, the other one is that you check if `Meta_Pre_MinContri` equals a character string `"character(0)"`. This solves both these problems:

```
Meta_Pre_MinContri[length(Meta_Pre_MinContri) == 0] <- NA
```